# Poisson Tail probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a normal distribution although every single number occurs with some probability (including infinity) however we have the 3$\sigma$ rule to upper and lower bound the outcomes and it is very acceptable in the literature. 
Is there a similar rule for Poisson?

Via computer simulations I can see that I get CDF=0.998 when I set the summation of outcomes from zero to 8*$\mu$ ($\mu$ is the mean of the Poisson). The problem is that, I don't have any lemma, or theorem to support that (I know I can easily proof it, but I am looking for something standard in the literature). Any help, suggestions would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Please consider accepting answers to other question you asked, when others took time to answer your question by clicking on the tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like Chebyshev's inequality can bound the size of the tail

$P(|X-\mu|>k\sigma) \leq 1/k^2$

Where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.

I guess you want $1/k^2 = 1-0.998$

For this, $k=\sqrt{500}$. This may be a loose bound but it works for every random variable, not just the Poisson one.

For a Poisson, $\mu=\sigma^2$

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing that out, I want to know if there is something like the 3*$\sigma$ rule of the normal distribution, which is well known and acceptable. In other words, I want to know if there is a rule rather than back-solving the CDF equation to know what my mean should be.

Comment: @Anderson i gave you that... If you read carefully. Note the inequality does not use the CDF...

Comment: @Anderson before we go any further, please accept answers to your other questions...

Comment: do not get me wrong I am thankful for your help but I was looking for something that is a non-back solve equation. Than you again for your help.

Comment: @Anderson i am lost for words, if you cant solve this. God help you... You dont know how to arrange for $k$?

Comment: @Anderson and you ignored my request for accepting any answers. Good luck getting help here.

Comment: @Anderson i didnt say you need to accept mine, but do you get the answer now?